# automatically create and convert graph(bar graph and pie chart) into pdf in iOS without creating a uiview for graphs

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, pdf-generation, core-plot

I want to generate PDF for reporting purpose. The PDF will contain Bar graph as well pie charts with little textual data. The PDF so generated will then be mailed using smtp client of iOS. I dont need to show any kind of view of graphs. I just want to mail the PDF.

Is it possible to dynamically create pdf with graph in background using core-plot and then mail with pdf attachment? I have found tutorials for creating PDFs, core plot(with UIView) and smtp mail client. I have also found codes for converting UIView(created for core plot graph) into images and then put the images into PDFs and mail it.

Can i do the task without creating UIView for Graph?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to add the graph to a hosting view just to create an image or PDF. Set the graph bounds to the desired size and call `-dataForPDFRepresentationOfLayer`. This method returns an `NSData` object containing the PDF data.